# Using CSRF in an AJAX Call causes Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, csrf

I am struggling to figure out why my code is returning an error that is being caused by using CSRF in an Ajax call. The error is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous>
```

Here is my AJAX Call including setup:

```
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

$.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
           }
          }
        });

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url : '/api/uservenue/',
     data: {
        'cafeName': cafeName,
        'list_id':  1,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value
         },

      success: function(data){
         console.log('User clicked: ' +  data)
       },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
      }
   });
```

Here is my views.py file

```
[...]
class UserVenue(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserVenueSerializer
    queryset = UserVenue.objects.all()
   
    @ensure_csrf_cookie
    def get_queryset(self):
        cafeName = self.request.GET.get('cafeName', None)
        print(cafeName)

        return UserVenue.objects.all()
[...]
```

**What I've tried**

- My JS script is at bottom of html file.
- I've tried a bunch of different edits and tweaks based on reading through documentation/SO/Reddit suggestions.
- I tried using method_decorators, but this seemed to raise more errors.

I'd be grateful for any  advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `{% csrf_token %}` in your template?

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I thought that the ``'csrfmiddlewaretoken': document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value`` clearly wrong. I added it and it seems to have overcome that error but is now throwing this one instead: ``Uncaught ReferenceError: csrfSafeMethod is not defined``

Comment: You've missed out the `csrfSafeMethod` [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request).